# Firebase cloud function change event timestamps wrong

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

we are building a system where changes in Firestore produce PubSub-message on which other components may act.

[Firestore events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) are used to implement this. The system keeps a history of changes for each document as subcollection of the document. To reduce the size of the PubSub-messages we are only sending references to documents in this subcollection. One before and one after the change. To allow our function to not waste time with queries to figure out what the last state was we are using the timestamps on the change events as ids.

env.ts:

```ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import {handler} from '@handlers/rootCollection';

//noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
export const handlerFunction = functions.firestore
    .document('rootcollection/{documentID}')
    .onWrite(handler.process.bind(handler));
```

rootCollection.ts:

```ts
import {DocumentSnapshot} from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore';
import {Change, EventContext} from 'firebase-functions';

interface MessageI extends Object {
    eventID: string;
    ref: string;
    beforeID: string | null;
    afterID: string | null;
    fcfReceived: number | null;
}

class WriteHandler {
    public name: string;

    public constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public async process(change: Change<DocumentSnapshot>, context: EventContext): MessageI {
        const afterExists = change.after.exists;
        const beforeExists = change.before.exists;
        const afterID = afterExists ? change.after.updateTime.toMillis().toString() : null;
        const beforeID = beforeExists ? change.before.updateTime.toMillis().toString() : null;

        return {
            'eventID': context.eventId,
            'ref': change.before.ref.path,
            'beforeID': beforeID,
            'afterID': afterID,
            'fcfReceived': Date.now()
        };
    }
}

export const itinerariesHandler = new WriteHandler(
    'rootCollectionHandler'
);
```

Now we are pretty surprised that the data is correctly reflecting the before and after states but the timestamp seems to be the after.timestamp.

Published message 429345402459000 to topic. Message:

```
{
  "eventID":    "389fe158-115a-43ca-9fdd-ec9737af066f-0",
  "ref":        "collection/VMDcsHirbB2coyaXF5wZ",
  "beforeID":   "1552298315479",
  "afterID":    "1552298315479",
  "fcfReceived": 1552298315575,
}
```

It seems counterintuitive that `change.before.updateTime` is containing the time when the change was done. But i cannot find a explicit mention in the documentation.

Is this behavior intended? Is there another way to find a unique id for the before state?

Regards,
Carsten

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. How is `updateTime` populated? How is the function declared and invoked? Can you update your question to show the minimal-but-*complete* Cloud Function that reproduces the problem, and the client-side invocation that triggers it?

Comment: Sure. I hope the edit helps. The invocations are by a java 8 backend via the firestore sdk libraries with normal set and update operations. 
If something else is unclear let me know.

Comment: I'm asking around. At first glance this sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This is bug in the Firestore bindings for Cloud functions. It indeed sets the `before.updateTime` and `after.updateTime` to the same value.

We filed a bug internally to get this fixed. But there is no timeline for when this fix will be available.

Until that time the best I can think of is to add an `lastUpdated` field to the document data, and validate that is the current server-side timestamp in your security rules. That way you can get the `before.data().lastUpdated` and `after.data().lastUpdated` to do the comparison. This should at least allow you to implement the behavior, until the problem is fixed.